# How to remove file with DBMS_SCHEDULER in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dbms-scheduler

I use `DBMS_SCHEDULER.PUT_FILE` to write file to a specified remote host.

Is there a procedure for deleting the created files?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no an equivalent in `DBMS_SCHEDULER` for removing a file in a remote host using the scheduler agent.

> **PUT_FILE Procedure**
>
> This procedure saves a file to the operating system file system of a
> specified remote host or of the local computer. It differs from the
> equivalent UTL_FILE procedure in that it uses a credential and can
> save files to a remote host that has only a Scheduler agent (and not
> an Oracle Database) installed.

However, you can overcome this limitation by creating a remote job that runs a `utl_file.fremove` or a shell script installed on the remote host to delete the file pass as parameter in the remote host

Example using `EXTERNAL_SCRIPT` type for remote job

```
create or replace procedure my_delete_job ( pname in varchar2 , pfiletodelete in varchar2 )
is
v_job pls_integer;
begin 
    select count(*) into v_job from dba_scheduler where job_name = upper(pname);
    if v_job = 1 
    then 
        dbms_scheduler.drop_job ( job_name => upper(pname) , force => true );
    end if;
    -- UNIX
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job(
        job_name             => 'MY_SH_DELETE',
        job_type             => 'EXTERNAL_SCRIPT',
        job_action           => '/path/my_delete_script.sh '||pfiletodelete||' ',
        auto_drop            => FALSE,
        enabled              => FALSE);
     DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute('MY_SH_DELETE', 'credential_name', 'MY_OS_REMOTE_CRED');
     DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute('MY_SH_DELETE', 'destination', 'host.domain:scheduleragentport');
     DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable('MY_SH_DELETE');
END;
/

exec my_delete_job ( 'MY_DELETE_JOB' , '/home/user/file.txt' );
```

Keep in mind that remote jobs are normally detached, so you need to consider a way to handle exceptions.

Of course, you can instead create a procedure in the remote database to use the `UTL_FILE` package. However, **the advantage of using external scripts is that you can run remote jobs in hosts which don't have an Oracle database installed.**

This article is a good example on how to handle exceptions on remote jobs.

[Remote Jobs](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/scheduler-enhancements-11gr1#creating_remote_external_jobs)

Comment: @enfix , any feedback about this workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not with `DBMS_SCHEDULER`. Use [`UTL_FILE.FREMOVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS70924) instead.

> This procedure deletes a disk file, assuming that you have sufficient privileges.

Comment: there is a `put_file`  procedure inside `dbms_scheduler` for the remote scheduler agent , since 11g. I think the question refers to this

Comment: yes, I write to remote scheduler agent. With UTL_FILE how can I manage file on the scheduler?